# $fotorama not loading consistantly

Tags: javascript, magento2.4, fotorama

I know this has been asked before, but I haven't been able to find a solution. I'm using the latest version of Magento 2 with the Porto theme. Occasionally things will load ok (especially in Firefox), but $fotorama doesn't load consistently, and as a result, images don't look right.

What I've tried:

- disabling lazyload for product images
- disabling the old media gallery
- running the resize command for all images
- removing gallery from my attribute sets and only leaving image_gallery
- Clearing all caches (server and browser)
- reindexing
- calling the fotorama library in requirejs-config.js like this

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'fotorama/fotorama': 'fotorama/fotorama',
    },
    shim: {
        'fotorama/fotorama': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
    }
}
```

[image: console error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an external script that was causing this. I'm still not sure why, but in my case it was a script from Constant Contact (yours may be different).

Instead of including it in the header scripts, I moved it into a block (not sure if that did anything) and then I added an async tag to that script. That seems to have done it.

To troubleshoot, remove all of your third party scripts and see if that makes $fotorama run consistently. If it does, add the scripts back slowly until you figure out which one is breaking $fotorama.

Add an async tag to that script, and it should work.

Example

```
<script async> var _ctct_m = "<my cc id>"; </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had no error message and the only way I tracked it down was disabling modules.